# Fortran Package Manager exclude test code

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran-package-manager

I've building a library with Fortran Package Manager and it's packing up the test code from `test/` as part of the final library - everything works okay but I'd prefer to omit the test code from the final build.

Is there a way to do this with Fortran Package Manager? I can't see anything obvious in the documenation for `fpm.toml`

Answer (score 6):

> To disable the automatic discovery of tests targets set the auto-tests entry to false:

```
[build]
auto-tests = false
```

See: https://fpm.fortran-lang.org/en/spec/manifest.html#automatic-target-discovery

Comment: Okay that works, but then I can't run the tests. Is the solution to have a second fpm.toml file to allow test running?

Comment: A solution would be to comment the `auto-tests = false` line by putting a # at the start of the line. And removing it when needed.

You may also try that fpm option:  `--tests       build all tests (otherwise only if needed)`

Comment: Hm, I tried that, but it looks like it won't compile the tests unless auto-tests is there. I was hoping to have a solution where I wouldn't need to change fpm.toml

Comment: fpm is evolving quickly (the version 0.6 was recently released). If a functionality is lacking, you can post an issue here: https://github.com/fortran-lang/fpm/issues